# How to check if an application is installed in my windows through asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, registerhotkey

can anyone please guide me how to check wether an application(any windows software) is installed in a windows client machine by using asp.net.I `ve tried registeries but couldnt access them due to security issues.Is there any other way ? .

Answer (score 0):

You can't do much on a client machine when you're an untrusted site. Most sites use client-side plugins that call back to the website in question after they're done checking - Java, ActiveX controls, etc.. These all require explicit user confirmation to do what they do when accessing things like this. If any site could just access the registry and other data we'd have personal information leaking all over.

Comment: ty for your reply @Yushatak.but can you suggest any other way to find wether my application is installed in the client machine or not?